# Second yellow in football

Tags: rules, football, officiating

If a player deserves a second yellow should play stop immediately or can advantage be played and then the player sent off later?

Answer (score 4):

No. Advantage should not be played for an offence which will result in a red card, regardless of what the reason for that red card is, unless there is an immediate goalscoring opportunity for the opponent of the offending player.

See Law 12, part 3 of the IFAB Law Of The Game. Emphasis is added.

> **Advantage should not be applied in situations involving** serious foul play, violent conduct or **a second cautionable offence** unless there is a clear opportunity to score a goal. The referee must send off the player when the ball is next out of play, but if the player plays the ball or challenges/interferes with an opponent, the referee will stop play, send off the player and restart with an indirect free kick, unless the player committed a more serious offence.

Comment: The IFAB Law of the Game documents: http://www.theifab.com/log-documents and the 2019/20 english pdf version: http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/files/document-category/062019/frRhKJNjSBAtiyt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes referee could let the advantage and the game continue. After the next stoppage (and for a consequent fault only), the referee gives second yellow card without whistling the fault that caused the yellow.
Example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCl6MCoOi1Q) at 2 min 18

Comment: Play was stopped immediately for the straight red card. There was no second yellow card for Capuano, and there was no advantage played. The video does not have any relevance to the question here.

Comment: @Nij Here's a more [recent example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoNd7jBTN7Y). The play was not stopped, but the arbiter (again, Gianluca Rocchi) gives two yellow cards afterward. Do you think it was against the rules?

Comment: Play is not stopped at the moment of Blind's offence because the opponent had an immediate goalscoring opportunity. After that opportunity was blocked by Veltman's handball, there is a second player who should be sent off. Since there is no longer a goalscoring opportunity, play was stopped straight away, then both players are cautioned and sent off. This is exactly what I state in my answer; it does not match at all what is described in bklups's answer here. @defaultlocale

Comment: @Nij Ah, yes, you're absolutely right. Turns out I misunderstood your answer. I already upvoted it anyway. Thank you!